# iTextSharp Helvetica using ArialMT as actual font

Tags: c#, itext, font-family

I am creating an export from HTML using the Helvetica font family:

[image: Screen shot of HTML]

But when the PDF is created I get this:

[image]

And the font being used is definitely Arial rather than Helvetica because the top of the 't' is not flat:

[image]

Our project is loading fonts from the '\content\fonts' dir in the web solution, but I've cleared this out completely and the issues still persists.

All that is left after clearing it out is 6 fonts that I presume iText is picking up from my system or that come bundled.

Comment: You are confusing fonts in the pdf with fonts rendered. You have helvetica in the pdf but the the actual glyphs are not embedded thus the renderer (Acrobat or some other) uses whatever is available in your machine that is similar, as in family, to helvetica, in this case Arial, if it was linux it would be some other font. To solve it embedd the font in the pdf.

Comment: Questions like this can be avoided by reading the documentation and tutorials. The *standard Type 1 fonts* are **never** embedded if you don't provide PFB files. ISO 32000-2 explains that fonts that aren't embedded (such as the standard Type 1 fonts) can be substituted by another font. For further reading, go to https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml and https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/clone-examples-font-tutorial

Comment: By the way: the name **iTextSharp** has been abandoned two years ago in favor of **iText for .NET** (which explains why you can't tag questions as iTextSharp questions anymore). The current version is [iText 7.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/). It's unclear if you're using the old XML Worker, or the new pdfHTML add-on.